# node-red-contrib-protobuf not finding .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, node-red

I am using node-red on a heroku server using node-red-contrib-protobuf

I have tried many different relative paths to the .proto file. The problem is I keep getting this error:
"Proto file could not be loaded. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '"../src/assets/protocol_buffers_files/generic_message.proto"'

I have also tried this "/src/assets/protocol_buffers_files/generic_message.proto"

The instance of my node-red deployment is on heroku. The relative path is correct. Why can't node-red-contrib-protobuf find the proto file?

Comment: The relative path is most likely relative to the node's `.js` file, not the Node-RED userDIR

Comment: Yes you are correct so I put it under the ./.node-red folder and it works

Answer (score 0):

The protobuf files use the node-red prefix from the settings.  So the files need to be in that directory path.